# App stops working on S6 only

Tags: android, android-studio

I have no idea whats going on here. My app works perfectly fine on the J5 and J6, but it stops working on the S6 (same android version on all phones)

And it only stops when I have the following code:
When I publish, android studio says 0 errors and 0 warnings

I'm still pretty new to android studio, and I've tried it with Thread `myThread` and without thread

```
public class IntroPage extends AppCompatActivity {

private ImageButton btnSkip;
private ImageButton btnUpdate;

// need this for post
RequestQueue requestQueue;

@Override
protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    // full screen
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);

    setContentView(R.layout.intro_page);


    requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(getApplicationContext());

    // outlets
    btnSkip = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.btnSkip);
    btnUpdate = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.btnUpdate);

    // hide both on default
    btnSkip.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    btnUpdate.setVisibility(View.GONE);


    // when submit is clicked
    btnSkip.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

            Intent startMainScreen = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.class);
            startActivity(startMainScreen);
            finish();
        }
    });

    // update
    btnUpdate.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

            Intent intent = new Intent();
            intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
            intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_BROWSABLE);
            intent.setData(Uri.parse("https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=ddddddddd"));
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });


    // get app version
    PackageInfo pInfo = null;
    try {
        pInfo = getPackageManager().getPackageInfo(getPackageName(), 0);
    } catch (PackageManager.NameNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    String version = pInfo.versionName;
    final Integer versionCode = pInfo.versionCode;


    // conn
    Thread myThread = new Thread() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            StringRequest jsonObjectRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST,
                    "https://www.domain.com/appVersion.php", new Response.Listener<String>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(String response) {
                    try {
                        JSONObject responseJson = new JSONObject(response);
                        Log.i("JSON RESPONSE", responseJson.toString());

                        // check if we are up to date
                        if (responseJson.getInt("version") > versionCode) {
                            btnSkip.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                            btnUpdate.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        } else {
                            btnSkip.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        }
                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

                }
            }) {
                // This whole section can be deleted if we dont post vars
                @Override
                protected Map<String, String> getParams() throws AuthFailureError {
                    Map<String, String> parameters = new HashMap<>();
                    parameters.put("club", "Murmur");
                    parameters.put("device", "Android");

                    return parameters;
                }
            };
            jsonObjectRequest.setShouldCache(false);
            // requestQueue.getCache().remove("https://www.domain.com/appVersion.php");
            requestQueue.add(jsonObjectRequest);
        }
    };
    myThread.start();
}
}
```

Comment: please share the crash log

Comment: I think app crashes because you change the views from another thread.